# D3.js multifocii layout group nodes inside rectangles

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I want to group nodes and rectangles such that nodes with similar property goes to their respective rectangle.

The nodes will be categorised based on their properties.Please help, I am having a hard time finding the solution.

Comment: can you not just go through all the nodes, the nodes which correspond to a certain rectangle put into an array. Then go through that array and set their positions inside corresponding rectangle ? It depends how you want the final outcome to be. Do you just want them to be static inside the rectangle ?

Comment: There can be some motion inside the rectangle. Also let's assume that there are 5 rectangles then, I need to have 5 arrays for holding their corresponding nodes?

Comment: do these nodes link to each other ? If they dont, split the data up and create different force layouts in each rectangle

Comment: Yes the nodes will be linked to each other, see this link for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699307/d3-js-how-to-club-nodes-inside-rectangles-with-force-multifoci-layout

Comment: i know youll be able to set the positions of the nodes explicitly but you want movement so im unsure how to do that :/